# Parsing SQS POST message in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-sqs

I have a web server and a worker that communicate over an SQS- you upload a picture to an S3 bucket through the server and it enqueues a message to the SQS so the worker will get it from the bucket, resize it and upload the resized image to the same bucket.
I have configured the worker to get notifications from the SQS when a new message arrives (POST) but I can't seem to parse it successfully and get the image name (it's a huge JSON).
How do I extract the file name from it if I wrote a message to the SQS with:

```
var params = {
        MessageBody:  JSON.stringify({data: msg.file}),
        QueueUrl: queueUrl
    };
SQS.sendMessage(params, function(err, data)...
```

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Too little details, too much assumption. What is the worker you are talking about?  You own code or some standard library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aws-sdk library? here is the docs from there: https://milesplit.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/using-sqs-with-node/

Here is the summary: first connect to the sqs:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    awsCredentialsPath = './aws.credentials.json',
    sqsQueueUrl = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123455678/test-queue',
    sqs;

// Load credentials from local json file
AWS.config.loadFromPath(awsCredentialsPath);
// Instantiate SQS client
sqs = new AWS.SQS().client;
```

Or, if you don't want to use external file:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    sqsQueueUrl = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123455678/test-queue',
    sqs;

// Load credentials from local json file
AWS.config.update({
   "accessKeyId": "YOUR AWS PUBLIC KEY",
   "secretAccessKey": "YOUR AWS SECRET KEY",
   "region": "us-east-1"
});
// Instantiate SQS client
sqs = new AWS.SQS().client;
```

Then - read the message:

```
sqs.receiveMessage({
   QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
   MaxNumberOfMessages: 1, // how many messages do we wanna retrieve?
   VisibilityTimeout: 60, // seconds - how long we want a lock on this job
   WaitTimeSeconds: 3 // seconds - how long should we wait for a message?
 }, function(err, data) {
   // If there are any messages to get
   if (data.Messages) {
      // Get the first message (should be the only one since we said to only get one above)
      var message = data.Messages[0],
          body = JSON.parse(message.Body);
      // Now this is where you'd do something with this message
      doSomethingCool(body, message);  // whatever you wanna do
   }
 });
```

Comment: Hi Bison, yeah I did use it. My problem was that the JSON I got back from the SQS (not using sqs.receiveMessage but using app.post(/newImage, function(req, res) {...}) would refuse to be parsed! I got the data I've inserted with req.body.data and then got the msg.file the server enqueued.